# Tomcat8 don't working, where is issue?

Tags: tomcat8

Yesterday all working great, but today, i went to work and tomcat didn't work. When i try to open page of tomcat, server not response, but in command line say that hi is running. I don't understand this problem. log - catalina.2016-02-09.log is very big, but not have error. 
[Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RQeUHpAFUkTzhmbl81UG9VOGc/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the likely culprit in the stacktrace:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

That most likely means a zombie process of your tomcat was running and you started another instance.

And please, if you don't know what logs are, don't write stuff like "but not have error", there's at least two stack traces in that log.

Comment: sorry, but i mean. that not have [ERROR] like [INFO] or [WARNING]. When i restart virtual, i had 1 zombie process, but when i try to find this, i don't see it .`Tasks: 168 total,   1 running, 167 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie` How i may find and kill it?

Comment: In Java, unchecked exceptions make it to the console, or in Tomcat's case in the logs. Those are serious errors as well. You can't just grep for [ERROR]

Comment: Thanks! Resolve problem. I had tomcat6 and after reboot virtual machine, it system work 2 tomcat. Thank you very much!